# How to place an output for every single thread in a single line in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization, system.out

I am learning multithreading, but at the same time I am not very experienced in Java. From this example from [here](https://www.nakov.com/inetjava/lectures/part-1-sockets/InetJava-1.3-Multithreading.html)

the output is this

```
thread1: Java
thread2: Java
thread1: is
thread2: is
thread1: hot,
thread1: aromatic,
thread2: hot,
thread1: and
thread1: invigorating.
Thread 1 is dead.
thread2: aromatic,
thread2: and
```

Is it possible to have an output like this

```
thread1:Java is hot, aromatic, and invigorating. is dead.
thread2:Java is hot, aromatic, and
```

So basically that the output of thread1 is always chained in line one in the terminal and thread2 in line2?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a StringBuilder to append the Strings to what you already have at that point, and print the complete String when you get to the end of processing:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(text);
```

Then use

```
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This will show the result at the end of processing.

Note that if multiple threads are modifying the same instance of a `StringBuilder` in your application, then some of the modifications may be lost. In that case you should use `StringBuffer` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have an output like this
>
> thread1:Java is hot, aromatic, and invigorating. is dead.
>
> thread2:Java is hot, aromatic, and

Yes, of course, you just need to ensure that each thread prints the entire string at one go.

> So basically that the output of thread1 is always chained in line one
> in the terminal and thread2 in line2?

There is several ways of achieve this, for instance you can use a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html):

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for
> each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful
> in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must
> occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because
> it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

to coordinate the threads so that the output happens one before of the other.

Here is a full example:

```
public class Mult {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int total_threads = 2;
        final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(total_threads);
        String msg1 = "thread1:Java is hot, aromatic, and invigorating. is dead.";
        String msg2 = "thread2:Java is hot, aromatic, and";
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> parallel_task1(barrier, msg1));
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> parallel_task2(barrier, msg2));
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    }

    private static void parallel_task1(CyclicBarrier barrier, String msg1) {
        System.out.println(msg1);
        wait_for_barrier(barrier);
    }

    private static void parallel_task2(CyclicBarrier barrier, String msg1) {
        wait_for_barrier(barrier);
        System.out.println(msg1);
    }

    private static void wait_for_barrier(CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        try {
            barrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to user [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

An example of such approach:

```
public class Mult {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        final int total_threads = 2;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(total_threads);
        Future<String> future1 = executor.submit(Mult::parallel_task1);
        Future<String> future2 = executor.submit(Mult::parallel_task2);
        String thread1_msg = future1.get();
        String thread2_msg = future2.get();
        System.out.println(thread1_msg);
        System.out.println(thread2_msg);
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private static String parallel_task1() {
        return "thread1:Java is hot, aromatic, and invigorating. is dead.";
    }

    private static String parallel_task2() {
        return "thread2:Java is hot, aromatic, and";
    }
}
```

> I am learning multithreading, but at the same time I am not very
> experienced in Java. From this example from here

IMO you should not lose too much time trying to coordinate threads so that they print output nicely. Parallelism is more about, IMO, speedup applications, among others, than coordinating output. It is much easier to either just output as it is or just use one thread to be responsible for the outputting. This type of tutorials use output as example because it is more user-friendly, but from my experience I never had to coordinate output coming from `System.out`.